# Finding optimum path through graph search

Tags: algorithm

I am currently working on Euler 411 https://projecteuler.net/problem=411.

I have figured out the mod exponentiation simplification to find all the coordinates in a reasonable amount of time and store the coordinates in files (70-200MB).

I also can plot coordinates and possible solutions. This is not the optimal solution. The optimal solution for this problem hits the maximum amount of stations.
[image]

Here's an image of N = 10000, PE reports 48 is the correct answer. The red line approximator gets 36. 504 coordinates.
[image]

N = 7**5 (16807) (actual from problem). Red line gets 159 points, 14406 unique coordinates.[image]

This is a search problem right? Am I missing something? I have tried greedy search with a density heuristic to get an approximate search, but it is not good enough to approximate the solution to the biggest problems. It would take days to finish. I have not tried an exact search like A* because it would be slower than greedy. BFS is out of the question.

Any hints? NO SPOILERS PLEASE!! There must be a way to eliminate nodes from this massive search space I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered that there may be a pattern in where the points occur...and hence the function value? You should solve small cases (of `k`) by hand! Also check that there is nothing special about `S(k^5)`. Finally, the second to last line of the problem statement seems a little suspicious, giving you particular information about S(123) and S(10000). If `S(10000)` is so low at forty-eight, it seems certain you are missing something and the search space need not be diabolical. So to my first reading, it does not appear to be a brute force search problem.

Comment: 10^4 is 10000, the example they provide S(10^4) = 48. As far as I can see, the search space is ****ing diabolical

Comment: Don't concentrate on large plots, just look for patterns in the solution on graphs of smaller cases. (It would be more useful to show us these graphs if you remain stuck) For example if it is indeed always concentrated on the main diagonal, it's perhaps linear time to build a solution there starting at the middle point.